# Difference between CC BY-SA 3.0 and CC BY 3.0

Tags: licensing

Comparing [CC BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) 3.0 and [CC BY 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/), both permits that you share ou even modify the material, under the term that you give credit, link the license and inform in case of any changes.

But in CC BY-SA, if you transform the material, those modifications should be distributed under the same license (or a compatible one, if I got it right). CC BY does not have such a term.

So, what's that mean? If someone got my game under CC BY, can they change it and distribute it under a different license, even a closed-source license?

In the case of CC BY-SA, in the same scenario, this version should be distributed as CC BY-SA as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have recently seen this discussion on the topic: https://discuss.okfn.org/t/reasons-to-use-a-cc-by-sa-licence-instead-of-cc-by/1765

So yes, as your questions suggests, if licensed under CC BY, closed source redistribution is possible. If the license includes a -SA (share alike) clause, the same license has to be used for redistribution.

In both cases, the copyright/credits and indication of changes must stay.

Disclaimer: I am no expert on the subject

This answer provides useful details too: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/1718